# Connecting to Foxx app as TCP bridge?

Tags: arangodb, foxx

I'm currently setting up my Foxx app as a GraphQL API endpoint and I would need to connect to it from the browser and the Node backend. There is an `arango.client` npm package that I'm thinking to install for my backend but it seems that it only supports HTTP. Wouldn't it be better to create a TCP connection bridge once (in Node) and communicate with it with lower latency and less overhead? I know that ArangoDB supports for TCP but why it is not implemented in `arango.client`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently ArangoDB only implements HTTP as transportation endpoint.

Source for irretation may be that specifying the *arangosh* commandline parameter for the server connection looks like this:

`--server.endpoint tcp://127.0.0.1:8529`

But the protocol spoken there is HTTP.

One step to bypass the TCP stack could be to [use unix domain sockets](https://docs.arangodb.com/ConfigureArango/Arangod.html) for the HTTP communication. You can use [Raw routes](https://github.com/arangodb/arangojs#arbitrary-http-routes) to communicate with your Foxx service:

```
var db = require('arangojs')();
var myFoxxService = db.route('my-foxx-service');
myFoxxService.post('users', {
    username: 'admin',
    password: 'hunter2'
})
.then(response => {
    // response.body is the result of
    // POST /_db/_system/my-foxx-service/users
    // with JSON request body '{"username": "admin", "password": "hunter2"}'
});
```

ArangoDB 3.0 will bring [velocypack](https://github.com/arangodb/velocypack/) and later on raw tcp protocoll to sideline HTTP. Foxx support is also planned for this.

While arangojs is currently a pure js implementation, we plan to offer a native backend under a similar API in the future. So if you want to benefit of that, you should go with ArangoJS now.

Comment: Thanks for the response. It's great that you're planning to implement this feature, it will be very useful. It's not very crucial for me to have this feature right now, so I think I'll just wait until it would be implemented in Foxx. Thanx!